# kubectl unable to connect to server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubectl

i'm getting an error when running kubectl one one machine (windows)

the k8s cluster is running on CentOs 7 kubernetes cluster 1.7
master, worker

Here's my .kube\config

```
  
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://10.10.12.7:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: system:node:localhost.localdomain
  name: system:node:localhost.localdomain@kubernetes
current-context: system:node:localhost.localdomain@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: system:node:localhost.localdomain
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

the cluster is built using kubeadm with the default certificates on the pki directory

kubectl unable to connect to server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry I wasn't able to provide this earlier, I just realized the cause:

So on the master node we're running a kubectl proxy

```
kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'
```

I stopped this and voila the error was gone.

I'm now able to do

```
    kubectl get nodes
NAME                    STATUS    AGE       VERSION
centos-k8s2             Ready     3d        v1.7.5
localhost.localdomain   Ready     3d        v1.7.5
```

I hope this helps those who stumbled upon this scenario.

Answer (score 41):

One more solution in case it helps anyone:

**My scenario:**

- using Windows 10
- Kubernetes installed via Docker Desktop ui 2.1.0.1
- the installer created config file at `~/.kube/config`
- the value in `~/.kube/config` for `server` is `https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443`
- using proxy

**Issue:** `kubectl` commands to this endpoint were going through the proxy, I figured it out after running `kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify cluster-info dump` which displayed the proxy html error page.

**Fix:** just making sure that this URL doesn't go through the proxy, in my case in bash I used `export no_proxy=$no_proxy,*.docker.internal`

Comment: `no_proxy=${no_proxy},.docker.internal` worked on MacOS also

Comment: in my case i also needed to `export NO_PROXY=${no_proxy},.docker.internal`

Comment: Yes, I have to use the upper case NO_PROXY too.
Versions: k8s: v1.18.8; docker: 19.03.13
MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: appended ```*.docker.internal``` to my no_proxy env worked!

Comment: For me, I had to add the `cluster.clusters[0].server` value (from kubeconfig) to the comma seperated  `NO_PROXY`  environment variable

Comment: For me, executing the `kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify cluster-info dump` command twice solved the issue. But, Why/How does it resolve the problem?

Answer (score 39):

So kubectl doesn't trust the cluster, because for whatever reason the configuration has been messed up (mine included). To fix this, you can use openssl to extract the certificate from the cluster

```
openssl.exe s_client -showcerts -connect IP:PORT
```

IP:PORT should be what in your config is written after `server:`

Copy paste stuff starting from `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` to `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` (these lines included) into a new text file, say... myCert.crt If there are multiple entries, copy all of them.

Now go to .kube\config and instead of

```
certificate-authority-data: <wrongEncodedPublicKey>`
```

put

```
certificate-authority: myCert.crt
```

(it assumes you put myCert.crt in the same folder as the config file)
If you made the cert correctly it will trust the cluster (tried renaming the file and it no longer trusted afterwards).
I wish I knew what encoding certificate-authority-data uses, but after a few hours of googling I resorted to this solution, and looking back I think it's more elegant anyway.

Comment: Thank you, you are very insighful. From my experience, you can see what's inside certificate-authority-data with:   `echo certificate-authority-data-string | base64 --decode`    It just shows the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- xx -----END CERTIFICATE----- ` (in other words a PEM X.509 certificate), so absolutely no surprises here.

Answer (score 24):

For my case, its simple worked by adding  `--insecure-skip-tls-verify`  at end of `kubectl` commands, for single time.

Comment: This is really bad advice in the general sense.

While this "works" in the sense that your client can connect to the server, it also means you're potentially sending sensitive data through a compromised connection (a man-in-the-middle proxy, for example).

Comment: Thanks for it. Even though it's not the solution, but it's a workaround.

Answer (score 22):

Run:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials standard-cluster-1 --zone us-central1-a --project devops1-218400
```

here `devops1-218400` is my project name. Replace it with your project name.

Comment: Also replace `standard-cluster-1` with your cluster name and `us-central1-a` with your zone (although I just left out the --zone option).  But this helped me, thank you!

Comment: ops doesnt run it on gcloud

Comment: This fixed it for me. I needed to run this for each of my projects.

Comment: if only cluster is created and you got the above error then:
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-1 --zone us-central1-c

Comment: Would `gcloud` works on my `rke` setup?

Comment: I needed to install `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` by running `gcloud components install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` first, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

I got the same error while running `$ kubectl get nodes` as a root user. I fixed it by exporting `kubelet.conf` to environment variable.

```
$ export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
$ kubectl get nodes
```

Comment: Better add it in ~/.bashrc ?

Comment: Yes you could add environment variable to `~/.bashrc` this way you would make it persistent for all bash sessions.

Answer (score 9):

This was happening because my company's network does not allow self signing certificates through their network. Try switching to a different network

Answer (score 8):

I my case I resolved this issue copying the kubelet configuration to my home kube config

cat  /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf  > ~/.kube/config

Answer (score 5):

For those of you that were late to the thread like I was and none of these answers worked for you I may have the solution:

When I copied over my .kube/config file to my windows 10 machine (with kubectl installed) I didn't change the IP address from 127.0.0.1:6443 to the master's IP address which was 192.168.x.x. (running windows 10 machine connecting to raspberry pi cluster on the same network). Make sure that you do this and it may fix your problem like it did mine.

Comment: Same exact problems. Did what you mention (That doesn't makes sense) and my result: `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Comment: I am not sure if you understood my comment. I copied the kubeconfig file from the master node of my cluster to my windows 10 computer. When the kubeconfig file was on the master node it worked because it was listening on the localhost of the server on 6443. Now that I was trying to connect to that server I needed to change the IP address in the kubeconfig to the network IP address of the master node.

Answer (score 5):

I removed/commented out this line
`certificate-authority-data:` and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

On GCP

check: gcloud version

-- localMacOS# gcloud version

Run:
--- localMacOS# gcloud container clusters get-credentials 'clusterName' \ --zone=us-'zoneName'

Get clusterName and zoneName from your console -- here: https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/list?

ref: .x509 @market place deployments on GCP #Kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but in case that also helps someone else here is another possible reason.

Let's assume that you have deployed Kubernetes with user x. If the .kube dir is under the /home/x user and you connect to the node with root or y user it will give you this error.

You need to switch to the user profile so kubernetes can load the configuration from the .kube dir.

**Update:** When copying the `~/.kube/config` file content on a local pc from a master node make sure to replace the hostname of the loadbalancer with a valid IP. In my case the problem was related to the dns lookup.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got this because I was not connected to the office's VPN

Answer (score 0):

In case of the error you should export all the kubecfg which contains the certs.  `kops export kubecfg "your cluster-name` and  `export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://"paste your S3 store"` .

Now you should be able to access and see the resources of your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, connecting to Azure, this was caused by our security proxy Netskope and was fixed by

```
kubectl config set-cluster my-cluster --certificate-authority=path\to\Netskope.pem

az aks get-credentials --resource-group my-resource-group --name my-cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

And there is another scenario for this issue:

1. The cluster is public running on remote servers. However, access to port `6443` is blocked by firewall. Only way in is via SSH with a tunnel forwarding traffic from a client's port `16443` to one of the remote master nodes' `127.0.0.1:6443`. *(Local port 6443 has not been used here due to Docker for Desktop using it already for its local cluster.)*
2. The kubectl configuration as provided on server via `kubectl config view --raw` has been transferred to the local client and set up there. Basically, running `kubectl` on a master node of cluster is working well.
3. Local client's configuration has been adopted to use `https://127.0.0.1:16443` instead of the master node's FQDN like e.g. `https://m1.cluster.com:6443`.

In this scenario, the issue seems to be related to the fact that whatever certificate the service is offering uses the FQDN or using an IP address with HTTPS causes issues with validating any certificate in general.

Hence, I had to utilize local client's **hosts** file to individually map the FQDN to `127.0.0.1`. After that, the adoption of hostname in step 3 above has to be reverted. Changing the port isn't an issue here and thus can stick to e.g. `16443` as illustrated here.

For those who don't know, in Windows the file is located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and it can be edited with `notepad` run with elevated privileges. Every line maps an IP address into a space-separated list of hostnames it is to be associated with. Thus you would have to add a line like this one there:

```
127.0.0.1 m1.cluster.com
```