# How to run remote code as user with certificate from a worker node

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubectl

I created a user in the Master.
First I created a key and certificate for him: `dan.key` and `dan.crt`

Then I created it inside Kubernetes:

```
 kubectl config set-credentials dan \ 
 --client-certificate=/tmp/dan.crt \
 --client-key=/tmp/dan.key
```

This is the `~/.kube/config`:

```
users:
- name: dan
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    client-certificate: /tmp/dan.crt
    client-key: /tmp/dan.key
```

I want to be able to run commands from a remote worker as the user I created.
I know how to do it with service account token:

```
kubectl --server=https://192.168.0.13:6443 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true --token="<service_account_token>" get pods
```

I copied the certifiacte and the key to the remote worker and ran:

```
[workernode tmp]$ kubectl --server=https://192.168.0.13:6443 --client-certificate=/tmp/dan.crt --client-key=/tmp/dan.key get pods
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I followed this question:
[kubectl unable to connect to server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234295/kubectl-unable-to-connect-to-server-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authori)
I tried like he wrote:

```
kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'
```

But I am still receiving:
`Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Answer (score 0):

> I copied the certifiacte and the key to the remote worker and ran:
>
> `[workernode tmp]$ kubectl --server=https://192.168.0.13:6443 --client-certificate=/tmp/dan.crt --client-key=/tmp/dan.key get pods`
>
> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

You were missing the critical piece of data telling `kubectl` how to trust the `https:` part of that request, namely `--certificate-authority=/path/to/kubernetes/ca.pem`

You didn't encounter that error while using `--token=...` because of the `--insecure-skip-tls-verify=true` which you should definitely, definitely not do.

---

> I tried like he wrote:
>
> `kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'`
>
> But I am still receiving:

You have followed the wrong piece of advice from whatever article you were reading; that `--accept-hosts` flag only controls the remote hostnames from which `kubectl proxy` will accept connections, and has zero to do with SSL anythings.