# kubectl giving error: Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: macos, kubernetes, docker-desktop

docker desktop on mac is getting error:

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

The [following answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234295/kubectl-unable-to-connect-to-server-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authori) didn't helped much:

My system details:

- Operating system: macOS Big Sur Version 11.6
- Docker desktop version: v20.10.12
- Kubernetes version: v1.22.5

When I do:

```
kubectl get pods
```

I get the below error:

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Comment: check which context you are using for connecting with the k8s cluster and check your certificate details in `.kube/config` file details

Comment: it is using correct context i.e docker-desktop

Comment: There are a lot of possible reasons why it happens. Have you tried to reset the kubernetes cluster in docker desktop? Do you use the latest available version of docker desktop? I have macOS 12.0.1 and docker desktop 4.5.0. It always starts without any issues.

Comment: before docker desktop i have tried rancher desktop and i can see context and cluster meta for that also, performing a clean up using command kubectl config delete-context  and kubectl config delete-cluster commands

Comment: @AmitMeena Oh, that may be the answer. Untick "enable kubernetes", then delete `~/.kube` where config is stored and then re-enable the kubernetes. Most likely config is still presented from previous rancher installation.

Comment: @moonkotte exactly that is what I did and resolved the issue. Can you make an answer and I can accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting the answer from comments

---

As appeared after additional questions and answers, there was a previous installation of `rancher` cluster which left its traces: certificate and context in `~/.kube/config`.

The solution in this case for local development/testing is to delete entirely `~/.kube` folder with configs and init the cluster from the scratch.

Comment: This is probably going to be a common issue as more people try `rancher-desktop` first, then re-install `docker-desktop` for some legacy compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a corporate laptop, and everything you do goes through a proxy, you will get this message. Hence, when docker desktop tries to connect to the server defined in `~/.kube/config`, it will try to go through the proxy and you will need the cert issued by the company. Long story short, you are getting blocked by the the company... To fix, you can add the no proxy props, adding what ever value server: internal.docker defined in`~/.kube/config` . Meaning, if I am connecting to docker cluster which runs locally in my laptop, do not direct my traffic through proxy.

When doing docker info, after setting no proxy, you should see something like this.

```
docker info | grep -i proxy

 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal,localhost,127.0.0.1,.local,.us.example.com,.examplecorp.com,.examplevcn.com,kubernetes.docker.internal
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5000
```