# Azure CLI - AKS Communication Issue

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-cli

i have problem in executing Kubectl commands, its errors out with 502 certificate error

**Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

[image]

I can able to login to az login after that I'm connecting with my AKS cluster by using below command

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group sitecore10.x-dev-k8s --name sitecore102-Dev-AKS-v1 --overwrite-existingenter code here
```

After that executing Kubectl get pods or Kubectl get services but it doesn't work

[image]

already tried adding environment variables
[image]

Opened .kube file and opened the same Url in browser , displayed the below error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to connect the AKS cluster from a windows machine:**

I have created **AKS** cluster, like below.

Go to **Azure Portal** > **Kubernetes Services** > **Create**.

[image]

Download **Kubectl** tool [here](https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.26.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe) and install the same on a windows machine, like below.

open **powershell** in **CMD** and navigate to download folder and run **kubectl.exe** , like below.

[image]

connect your cluster using **cloud shell** to download **.kube.config** file. like below.

[image]

once connected to the cluster, download the config file to the Local windows machine.

[image]

Create a folder with **.kube** name in your username folder and place the downloaded **config** file in the same folder.

```
Path  C:\Users\yourusername
```

[image]

Now run **kubectl** cmd to get the **AKS cluster** details from the windows machine, like below.

[image]

**Reference**:  [kubectl unable to connect to server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234295/kubectl-unable-to-connect-to-server-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authori) by **bherto39**.

Comment: Hi Venkat, thanks for analyzing the issue.  Appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved**
I got a chance to resolve this issue.
The actual issue is AKS URL (h**ttps://AKSInstance.hcp.westus.azmk8s.io:443**) is blocked by Company **Internet Monitoring Software** (Netskope).
i raised a support ticket to whitelist the URL https://*.azmk8s.io

**How to check the issue :**
C:\Users[YourUserName].kube open config file to identify the AKS URL, try opening the URL directly in the browser, if your getting 401 authentication issue then your good, otherwise if your getting error message related to certificate then it should be your Internet Monitoring software is blocking the AKS URL calls.